# Help identifying strange succulent (?) found growing near morning glories

Tags: identification, succulents, morning-glory

The strange succulent-looking plant in these photos appeared mysteriously growing near morning glories in a planter.  Could anyone help identify/explain?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a magnolia tree nearby, then I think you're looking at one of its seedpods that has fallen or been carried by animals to your morning glory.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!  You are correct, it turned out not to rooted to the ground but instead to be attached to a stem.  It must be a seedpod from a magnolia nearby in the neighborhood.  Mystery solved!